# If date of year 2020 have booking value less than 25 than replace it with last year 7 days value average in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I am working on a pandas dataframe and I have to replace column booking value if less than 25 with average of 7 days example `x = 22-03-2020` has booking value 3, I have to replace it

```
x = average(before 3 days + last year same date + after 3 days/7))
```

[image]

After replace

[image]

I have many values to replace, manually i am able to do it but i need some shortcut.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and come back with a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rolling` with `center=True`, but need all values of days, so add [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html), then add one year to `DatetimeIndex` and because leap year is 2020 is added `mean` for aggregate duplicates in end of February, last set values by mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2019-03-19', periods=8),
                 'Booking':[92,109,144,109,122,76,78, 3]}) 
df.loc[7, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-22')

df = df.set_index('date')

s = df['Booking'].asfreq('d').rolling(7, center=True).mean()
s.index = s.index + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
s = s.mean(level=0)
print (s)
date
2020-03-19           NaN
2020-03-20           NaN
2020-03-21           NaN
2020-03-22    104.285714
2020-03-23           NaN
   
2021-03-18           NaN
2021-03-19           NaN
2021-03-20           NaN
2021-03-21           NaN
2021-03-22           NaN
Name: Booking, Length: 369, dtype: float64
```

---

```
mask = df['Booking'].lt(25)

df.loc[mask, 'Booking'] = s
print (df)
               Booking
date                  
2019-03-19   92.000000
2019-03-20  109.000000
2019-03-21  144.000000
2019-03-22  109.000000
2019-03-23  122.000000
2019-03-24   76.000000
2019-03-25   78.000000
2020-03-22  104.285714
```